# Rest-Client Installation not working properly

Tags: ruby, installation, rest-client

The following error is displayed in command prompt in Windows 7

C:\Users\rd\Desktop\Training\Problem2\sudoku\sudoku>gem install rest-client
WARNING:  RubyGems 1.2+ index not found for:
        http://gems.rubyforge.org/

RubyGems will revert to legacy indexes degrading performance.
ERROR:  could not find gem rest-client locally or in a repository

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Default gem source has been changed from `http://gems.rubyforge.org` to `http://rubygems.org`

Remove rubyforge from your gem sources by doing so

```
gem source --remove http://gems.rubyforge.org/
```

Add rubygems to your gem sources by doing so

```
gem source --add http://rubygems.org
```

Now when you do `gem sources` then you will not have `http://gems.rubyforge.org` and `http://rubygems.org` should be present.

Comment: Still the error persists saying:

Error fetching http://rubygems.org:
        SocketError: getaddrinfo: temporary failure in name resolution. (http://rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)
Is it a temporary error due to a fault on the server side or something else?

Comment: looks like you are not able to access rubygems.org See if you can ping to it. Are you behind some firewall?

Comment: `gems.rubyforge.org`, `rubygems.org` and `gemcutter.org` now all point to the same IP address, so it doesn't really matter which ones you have in your `~/.gemrc`, although `rubygems.org` is the correct one, the other two are only for backwards-compatibility and may be deactivated in the future. `rubygems.org` had some troubles recently, maybe it was just down while you were trying it?

Comment: @Jorg W Mittag very true, @Apoorv If you are not able to install the gem using `gem install` command due to issues with rubygems.org then you can clone or download the gem source and build/install the gem yourself locally.

Comment: Thanks for your advice but second error was because of my network failure,so thanks a lot for helping